# Vim - Pydoc plugin not working with operator mapping

Tags: vim

I have a small operator mapping for use with the [Pydoc plugin](https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim).  The code for it is below:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>d :set operatorfunc=<SID>PydocOperator<cr>g@
vnoremap <buffer> <localleader>d :<c-u>call <SID>PydocOperator(visualmode())<cr>

function! s:PydocOperator(type)
    let l:orig_register = @@

    if a:type ==# 'v'
        normal! `<v`>y
    elseif a:type ==# 'char'
        normal! `[v`]y
    else
        return
    endif

    execute 'Pydoc ' . shellescape(@@)
    let @@ = l:orig_register
endfunction
```

However, vim throws an error:

```
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>117_ShowPyDoc
```

The same error happens if I copy some text manually and run this command:

```
execute 'Pydoc ' . shellescape(@@)
```

This is very odd, considering that the `:Pydoc` should work as a normal command, taking one argument as its input.  I looked at the code where the `:Pydoc` command is defined, (that line of code is [here](https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/python_pydoc.vim#L247)) and discovered that passing an argument to the `:Pydoc` command that is in quotes might be causing an issue.  So I ran `:Pydoc 'sys'` to see if it would throw the same error as the operator mapping, which it did.  So if it is having an issue with the quotes around the argument, how do I format the `execute` command so that it doesn't give an invalid argument?

Comment: Also, you should use `:map <buffer>` in conjunction with `<localleader>`, so that it's only defined in Python buffers (like the `:Pydoc` command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shellescape()` function is not necessary for the `:Pydoc` command.  `shellescape` includes quotes in the returned string, which causes `:Pydoc` to self destruct.  However, if the command were `:grep`, for instance, `shellescape` would need to be used.

Relevant help topics:

```
:help shellescape()
:help 'operatorfunc'
:help :map-operator
```